# Build pipeline to create azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

I want to create azure VM using DevOps pipelines. can you help me out which process/task should I use? And what are the pre-requirements?

I tried with Arm template deployment, azure deployment but not worked yet.

Comment: Please refer below URI to create an Virtual Machine. [Windows / Linux] using DevOps pipelines.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/deploy-linux-vm?view=azure-devops&tabs=javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach is using Azure CLI task in your build pipeline.

Here is a sample:

[image]

[image]

Check the VM in Azure Portal:

[image]

Refer to this official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-cli